# Geth: What parts of CallMsg need to be filled in during "view" calls with CallContract() in ethclient.go?

Tags: go-ethereum

The CallContract() method in ethclient.go takes an argument of the CallMsg type. If I just want to read the output of a "view" function, can I leave a lot of the fields empty (0)? For example, From, Gas, GasPrice, GasFeeCap, GasTipCap, Value? And fill in only To and Data?

```
// CallMsg contains parameters for contract calls.
type CallMsg struct {
    From      common.Address  // the sender of the 'transaction'
    To        *common.Address // the destination contract (nil for contract creation)
    Gas       uint64          // if 0, the call executes with near-infinite gas
    GasPrice  *big.Int        // wei <-> gas exchange ratio
    GasFeeCap *big.Int        // EIP-1559 fee cap per gas.
    GasTipCap *big.Int        // EIP-1559 tip per gas.
    Value     *big.Int        // amount of wei sent along with the call
    Data      []byte          // input data, usually an ABI-encoded contract method invocation

    AccessList types.AccessList // EIP-2930 access list.

    // For BlobTxType
    BlobGasFeeCap *big.Int
    BlobHashes    []common.Hash
}
```